How to find out which column is failing if type is number and it exceeds the length in JPA insert operation
I am trying to insert a record in a Oracle 11g table which have around 100 columns.
 repository.saveAndFlush(nextObj);

When i am inserting JPA is throwing exception like below, it not telling me which column its failing . Is there any way i can throw exception with exact failing column name .
could not execute batch [ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision
allowed for this column.

You have an Oracle (ORA-) error. You will need to show us an Oracle statement.

Turn on logging of SQL and values in Hibernate.
